# How to install a validated SSL certificate on Ubiquiti UniFi Network Application (Controller) running on Linux

Tags: certificate, ubiquiti, unifi

I want to replace the self signed Unifi certificate used for the web interface of the UniFi Network application / server v6.5 (on Ubuntu 18 Linux) with a signed (wildcard) certificate and private key I already have.

Where should I put the private key, where the cert and how do I configure the UniFi Network Application / Controller to use this cert?

I found some information but none of them worked for me or seemed to be ways to complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to UniFi base folder

```
cd /usr/lib/unifi
```

Copy your private key file and the pem file (single file including the cert, intermediate ca cert and chain to the root if needed) to `/usr/lib/unifi/`

Convert your private key from PKCS#8 to PKCS#1 if necessary (when you get an error message like *java.lang.IllegalStateException: private.key contains an artifact that is not a key pair: org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo*)

```
# OpenSSL 2:
openssl rsa -in private.key -out transformed-private.key

# OpenSSL 3:
openssl pkey -in private.key -traditional -out transformed-private.key
```

Stop the UniFi Network application

```
service unifi stop
```

Import cert and key to keystore

```
java -jar lib/ace.jar import_key_cert transformed-private.key certificate.pem
```

*Optionally you can add a CA cert as an additional, last parameter (if it is not already included in the certificate.pem)*

Start the UniFi Network application

```
service unifi start
```

Clean up and delete your cert and private key files.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Additionally, if you are using an internal CA (As I am) you will need to also upload the CA certificate to the server and specify it at the end-

```
sudo java -jar lib/ace.jar import_key_cert transformed-private.key certificate.pem ca-certificate.pem
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This procedure works from a Windows client

You need two files (both in PEM format);

- `unifi-core.crt` The certificate
- `unifi-core.key`Your private key

1. Enable SSH on https://10.0.0.1/settings/system
2. Connect and check existing files

From cmd.exe

```
ssh 10.15.15.1 -l root
cd /mnt/data/unifi-os/unifi-core/config/
ls -lh
```

3. Upload the new cert and private key

From (another) cmd.exe

```
scp unifi-core.crt root@10.0.0.1:/mnt/data/unifi-os/unifi-core/config/unifi-core.crt
scp unifi-core.key root@10.0.0.1:/mnt/data/unifi-os/unifi-core/config/unifi-core.key
```

4. Verify the new files and apply

From the existing SSH connection (step 2)

```
ls -lh
unifi-os restart
```

5. Disable SSH https://10.0.0.1/settings/system